# Rabbit MQ declarative clustering

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ node running on a Windows 2012 server (rabbit@my-server-1).

I am creating a second node (rabbit@my-server-2) on a seperate server (also Windows 2012) and would like to cluster it with the existing node. The deployment of the second node is via Octopus Deploy and to make life easier I would like to have the clustering automatically done on startup of the node.

Reading the documentation (https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) leads me to believe I just need to add the following to the rabbitmq.conf file:

```
cluster_nodes.disc.1 = rabbit@my-server-1
```

However doing so causes the node to not start. The erl.exe process starts using 100% cpu and I see the following message in the erl_crash.dump file:

```
Slogan: init terminating in do_boot (generate_config_file)
```

I believe this is symptomatic of an invalid config file, and indeed removing these config entries allows me start the node fine.

I am able to cluster to the existing node manually via the relevant rabbitmqctl commands, but would prefer the declarative solution if possible.

I'm running RabbitMQ v3.7.4 and Erlang v20.3

So, what am I doing wrong? I've done some googling but haven't found anything that helps.

**EDIT**

Config file in full is:

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cacert.pem
ssl_options.certfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/key.pem
ssl_options.password = xxxxxxx
ssl_options.verify = verify_none
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2

web_stomp.ssl.port       = 14879
web_stomp.ssl.backlog    = 1024
web_stomp.ssl.certfile   = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.keyfile    = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/key.pem
web_stomp.ssl.cacertfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cacert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.password   = xxxxxxx

cluster_nodes.disc.1 = rabbit@my-server-1
```

Comment: Could you please post your configuration file in its entirety?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the clustering-information like it is written in the doc under ["Config File Peer Discovery Backend"](https://www.rabbitmq.com/cluster-formation.html#peer-discovery-classic-config)

this would leave you with a configfile like this:

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cacert.pem
ssl_options.certfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/key.pem
ssl_options.password = xxxxxxx
ssl_options.verify = verify_none
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2

web_stomp.ssl.port       = 14879
web_stomp.ssl.backlog    = 1024
web_stomp.ssl.certfile   = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.keyfile    = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/key.pem
web_stomp.ssl.cacertfile = e:/Rabbit/Certificates/cacert.pem
web_stomp.ssl.password   = xxxxxxx

cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.1 = rabbit@my-server-1
cluster_formation.classic_config.nodes.2 = rabbit@my-server-2
```